# Akka thread safety with Futures

Tags: scala, akka

I have an actor that has a mutable state. In my receive method, I pattern match the messages and call some service that would return a Future. This Future would modify the state in my Actor instance. Is this state not thread safe? Since the Future would be executing in a different thread, is the state in my Actor this guaranteed to be thread safe?

Comment: You can use the pipeTo pattern to work with Futures and mutable state inside an actor.

Comment: How about doing a context.become?

Comment: @user3102968 context.become still doesn't solve the issue when modifying internal mutable state. The Actor can be processing a different message by that time and you will have a race condition when the Future is also modifying internal state.
Also if my answer is the solution, please mark it as accepted, thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

No that will not be threadsafe as you correctly assumed. Futures run on any thread that the execution context provides.

The way to solve this is to pipe it back to the same actor. All actor's inputs must always be messages. You can find the [documentation here](http://doc.akka.io/docs/akka/snapshot/scala/futures.html).

Some example code:

```
import akka.pattern.pipe

//... inside the Actor somewhere:
val futureResult: Future[YourType] = something.thatReturnsAFuture()
futureResult.pipeTo(self)
```

And then amend your receive block so the result will be processed after the future completes and it is sent back to this actor:

```
case result: YourType => //...
```